# Python subprocess module pipes stop working with Apache Beam after several invocations

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, pipe, apache-beam

I'm using the python subprocess module to run a subprocess from an Apache Beam DoFn on MacOS.

The first several subprocess calls work fine, however at about the 7th subprocess call I start getting the error:

`OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

from within the subprocess module.

I've tried changing the files that I'm reading / piping, but this doesn't affect the resulting error.

I've tried isolating the issue to the following code, but this runs fine:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from subprocess import run, PIPE
import io

def run_subprocess(element):
    x = run(["ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "panic", "-t", '900', "-f", "mp3", "-i", "pipe:0", "-map_metadata", "-1", "-vn", "-acodec", 'pcm_s16le', "-ac",
            '2', "-ar", '44100', "-f", "wav", 'pipe:1'], input=element.read(), capture_output=True)
    yield x.stdout[:20]

def open_file(element):
    with open(element, 'rb') as f:
        data = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    data.seek(0)
    yield data

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    _ = (p
    | "A" >> beam.Create(['./test.mp3']*100)
    | "B" >> beam.ParDo(open_file)
    | "C" >> beam.ParDo(run_subprocess)
    | "D" >> beam.ParDo(print)
    )
```

The pipeline is relatively complicated compared to the above example, but the particular DoFn that fails is very similar to `run_subprocess` above.

I've tried catching the `OSError` and setting testing other uses of the subprocess module there. At that point, even just running `subprocess.run(['echo'], input=b'hi', capture_output=True)` or `Popen(['echo'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)` raises the same error. However, running `Popen(['echo'])` without the pipes causes no issues.

Any idea what is going on here? Could there be some interference between the pipes that Apache Beam uses and those that subprocess use? Or perhaps some system level limitation on pipe use / buffer sizes?